# Suggestion on C++ object serialization techniques

Tags: c++, serialization

I'm creating a C++ object serialization library. This is more towards self-learning and enhancements & I don't want to use off-the-shelf library like boost or google protocol buf.
Please share your experience or comments on good ways to go about it (like creating some encoding with tag-value etc).
I would like to start by supporting PODs followed by support to non-linear DSs.

Answer (score 1):

If you need serialization for inter process communication, then I suggest to use some interface language ([IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language) or [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Object_Class_%28ASN.1%29)) for defining interfaces.

So it will be easier to make support for other languages (than C++) too. And also, it will be easier to implement code/stub generator.

Comment: Yes, my intention is to send the object on wire. If I use IDL/ASN.1 then i'll have to use its corresponding compiler (idl compiler) for encoding my datatypes, which in essence would use (BER/PER) etc. I wanted to define my own encoding for packing the data and send it on wire.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on something similar for the last few months. I couldn't use Boost because the task was to serialize a bunch of existing classes (huge existing codebase) and it was inappropriate to have the classes inherit from the interface which had the serialize() virtual function (we did not want multiple inheritance).

The approach taken had the following salient features:

1. Create a helper class for each existing class, designated with the task of serializing that particular class, and make the helper class a friend of the class being serialized. This avoids introduction of inheritance in the class being serialized, and also allows the helper class access to private variables.
2. Have each of the helper classes (let's call them 'serializers') register themselves into a global map. Each serializer class implements a clone() virtual function ('prototype' pattern), which allows one to retrieve a pointer to a serializer, given the name of the class, from this map. The name is obtained by using compiler-specific RTTI information. The registration into the global map is taken care of by instantiating static pointers and 'new'ing them, since static variables get created before the program starts.
3. A special stream object was created (derived from `std::fstream`), that contained template functions to serialize non-pointer, pointer, and STL data types. The stream object could only be opened in read-only or write-only modes (by design), so the same serialize() function could be used to either read from the file or write into the file, depending on the mode in which the stream was opened. Thus, there is no chance of any mismatch in the order of reading versus writing of the class members.
4. For every object being saved or restored, a unique tag (integer) was created based on the address of the variable and stored in a map. If the same address occurred again, only the tag was saved, not the deep-copied object itself. Thus, each object was deep copied only once into the file.

A page on the web captures some of these ideas shared above: http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/lectures/cpp/Serialization.htm. Hope that helps.

Comment: [You don't need to inherit anything to make your classes serializable with Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion). Granted, you may need to modify the class such that the private variables are visible to the `serialize()` function if the public interface is not enough to serialize the class, but you don't need to inherit from anything.

Comment: Agreed. Boost, however, was way too much complexity to be brought in, given the already complex hierarchy we had in place. Something done by hand seemed more suitable and maintainable in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Somesh, your inputs are really helpful. I'm going through the link provided by you. I would be using the serialized object for communicating across the network. The article also talks about support for non-linear DS (thats good). I'll have more do discuss on this once i'm out with my first prototype :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article some years ago. Code and tools can be obsolete, but concepts can remain the same.

May be [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/MiMfcSerial.aspx) can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Emilio Garavaglia. I'll look into your article for insights